# Problem with glossaries and incorrect format of location class with \GlsAddLocation

Tags: listings, glossaries

Trying to use package `glossaries` leads to the following error messages in my case:

```
When starting user command "makeglossaries %": **Warning:** You may have forgotten to add a location class with \GlsAddLocation or you may have the format incorrect.

When starting PdfLaTeX: ! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.

Type H <return> for immediate help.
...
l.27 \end{theglossary}
\glossarypostamble
Try typing <return> to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type X <return> to quit.
)
Package babel Info: Redefining ngerman shorthand "|
(babel) in language on input line 248.
Package babel Info: Redefining ngerman shorthand "~
(babel) in language on input line 248.
Package babel Info: Redefining ngerman shorthand "|
(babel) in language on input line 248.
Package babel Info: Redefining ngerman shorthand "~
(babel) in language on input line 248.
[6
]
```

Problem is that everything works fine without my university's predefined design. Can anybody see what is the problem here?

```
\documentclass[type=msc,accentcolor=tud9b, 11pt, bigchapter, table, draft]{tudthesis}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{listings} 
\usepackage{my_style}

\AtBeginDocument{\let\textlabel\label}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage[nonumberlist,toc,xindy]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{bbrot}{name=Butterbrot,
description={Brot mit Butter drauf}}

\glsaddall

\begin{document}

\thesistitle{A}{B}
\author{C. D.}
\date{\today}

\referee{Prof. Dr.}{}

\makeSzMthesistitle

\printglossary

Foo

\end{document}
```

which makes use of my_style.sty:

```
\setinstitutionlogo{Abbildungen/logo_bs_j}

\parindent0mm

\lstset{ %
language=Matlab,                % choose the language of the code
basicstyle=\footnotesize,       % the size of the fonts that are used for the code
numbers=left,                   % where to put the line-numbers
numberstyle=\footnotesize,      % the size of the fonts that are used for the line-numbers
stepnumber=5,                   % the step between two line-numbers. If it's 1 each line will be numbered
numbersep=5pt,                  % how far the line-numbers are from the code
backgroundcolor=\color{white},  % choose the background color. You must add \usepackage{color}
showspaces=false,               % show spaces adding particular underscores
showstringspaces=false,         % underline spaces within strings
showtabs=false,                 % show tabs within strings adding particular underscores
frame=single,                   % adds a frame around the code
tabsize=2,                      % sets default tabsize to 2 spaces
captionpos=b,                   % sets the caption-position to bottom
breaklines=true,                % sets automatic line breaking
breakatwhitespace=false,        % sets if automatic breaks should only happen at whitespace
escapeinside={\%*}{*)}          % if you want to add a comment within your code
}

\gdef\TUD@thesis@referee{\PackageError{\@currname}{No '\noexpand\referee` given!\MessageBreak See documentation for details.}\@ehc}
\def\referee#1#2{\@ifnextchar[{\TUD@thesis@referee@three{#1}{#2}}{\TUD@thesis@referee@two{#1}{#2}}}
\def\TUD@thesis@referee@two#1#2{
\gdef\TUD@thesis@referee{#1\\#2}
}
\def\TUD@thesis@referee@three#1#2[#3]{
\gdef\TUD@thesis@referee{#1\\#2\\#3}
}

\newcommand{\makeSzMthesistitle}{%  \TUD@thesis@subsubtitle{\ifTUD@thesis@phd\TUD@thesis@titletype\fi%
Masterarbeit von \@author\ifTUD@thesis@birthplace\ aus \  %
\TUD@thesis@birthplace\else\ifTUD@thesis@phd\PackageError{\@currname}{No '\noexpand\birthplace` given!\MessageBreak See documentation for details.}\@ehc\fi\fi\\%
Matrikelnummer: xxxxxxx%
\ifTUD@thesis@phd{ --- Darmstadt --- D 17}\fi%
}
\TUD@thesis@institution{\TUD@thesis@department\\%
\TUD@thesis@group}%

\TUD@thesis@uppertitleback{%

    \vspace{15cm}
    \begin{minipage}[b]{\textwidth}
\@author\\  %  Verfasser
    Matrikelnummer: xxxxxxx\\[\baselineskip]
    %Art der Ausarbeitung\\     %  Art der Arbeit
    \@title\\                      % Titel der Arbeit
    \@subtitle\\[\baselineskip]    % Untertitel
    Eingereicht am: \@date\\[\baselineskip]   %
    Betreuung:\\
    \TUD@thesis@referee\\%[\baselineskip]    % Betreuung mit Abstand
    \\
    Technische Universität Darmstadt\\
    Institut für Verkehr\\
    Fachgebiet Bahnsysteme und Bahntechnik\\
    Otto-Berndt-Straße 2\\
    64287 Darmstadt
    \end{minipage}
}%
\if@twoside\else
\@TUD@thesis@restonesidetrue
\@twosidetrue \@mparswitchtrue
\fi
\TUD@thesis@maketitle%
\if@TUD@thesis@restoneside
\@twosidefalse \@mparswitchfalse
\fi
}
```

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: The message about `\GlsAddLocation` suggests that the location is using an unrecognised location. (That's a misprint in `makeglossaries`. The command name is actually `\GlsAddXdyLocation`. I need to fix that.) As I don't have your class file, I can't tell what it is, but if you look at the `.glo` file, there should be an `locref` element. For example `:locref {}{1}"`. If this has a different pattern, then [`\GlsAddXdyLocation`](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossaries-user.html#sec:xindyloc) needs to be added. The arguments depend on the `attr` value.

Comment: The missing `\item` error is probably caused by an empty glossary using the default `list` style.

Comment: Correction to my first comment: the arguments depend on the `locref` format not the `attr` value.

Comment: My .glo file said "(indexentry :tkey (("Butterbrot" "\\glossentry

{bbrot}") ) :locref "{}{-1}" :attr 

"pageglsnumberformat" ) ", so I added \GlsAddXdyLocation as an extra line, but without any effect: "! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have your class but from your comment

> .glo file said `"(indexentry :tkey (("Butterbrot" "\\glossentry {bbrot}") ) :locref "{}{-1}" :attr "pageglsnumberformat" ) "`

it looks as though you have a negative page number which `xindy` doesn't recognise. The following MWE below recreates the error:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[xindy]{glossaries-extra}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{bbrot}{name=Butterbrot,
description={Brot mit Butter drauf}}

\begin{document}
\setcounter{page}{-1}
\gls{bbrot}.

\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

The `xindy` transcript (`.glg` file) shows the following warning:

```
WARNING: location-reference "{}{-1}" did not match any location-class! (ignored)
```

The `makeglossaries` script detects this warning and shows the diagnostic message in your post:

```
You may have forgotten to add a location
class with \GlsAddLocation or you may have
the format incorrect.
```

(As mentioned in the comments, there's a misprint here, the command name is actually `\GlsAddXdyLocation`.) The syntax is

```
\GlsAddXdyLocation[prefix]{name}{definition}
```

The optional argument `prefix` is only needed if the document uses `hyperref` and `\theH`*counter* is defined as *prefix*`\the`*counter*. In this case, the prefix is empty. The `name` part is the name of the format, and `definition` is the `xindy` code that defines the location format.

`xindy` recognises `"arabic-numbers"` as the digits 0 to 9, but this doesn't allow for a sign (`+`/`-`). A new location can be added for negative page numbers using:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[xindy]{glossaries-extra}

\GlsAddXdyLocation{negativepage}{:sep "-" "arabic-numbers"}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{bbrot}{name=Butterbrot,
description={Brot mit Butter drauf}}

\begin{document}
\setcounter{page}{-1}
\gls{bbrot}.

\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

However, it does seem a little odd that the document has a negative page number. Not having the class file, this is just a guess, but it may be that the `page` counter is initialised to `-1` and only set to `1` at the start of the document. In which case, the problem may actually be due to the use of `\glsaddall` in the preamble, and could simply be solved by moving `\glsaddall` to the document.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[xindy]{glossaries-extra}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{bbrot}{name=Butterbrot,
description={Brot mit Butter drauf}}

\setcounter{page}{-1}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\glsaddall

\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

The error message

```
! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.27 \end{theglossary}
                      \glossarypostamble
```

is caused by an empty list. The same thing happens when you do

```
\begin{description}
\end{description}
```

which is essentially what happens when you use one of the `list` styles but there are no entries in the glossary (because all entries have been ignored by `xindy`/`makeindex` due to some problem). You need to delete the temporary `.gls` file before rebuilding the document (after fixing the problem).

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was exactly the problem! I did put \newglossaryentry before \pagenumbering{arabic} first. Changing this led to no further problems at all!

Comment: @D.Duesen It's okay to have `\newglossaryentry` in the preamble (in fact, it's better there), it's just the indexing commands like `\glsaddall` that need to go in the document.